# Converting Illuminate\Http\Request to array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making in use of a library that expects to receive a native PHP array such as is obtained from the global $_REQUEST.

Unfortunately in this instance, the Illuminate\Http\Request is an object, and seems to have quite a different structure to the native php array. Is there a method to convert that object to the same array that would be obtained via '$_REQUEST' (which doesn't work inside a laravel controller method).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32):

Illuminate\Http\Request has some nice methods to turn it into arrays.

```
// Where $request is an Illuminate\Http\Request instance
$request->all(); // Returns array with all elements.
$request->only(['key1', 'key2']); // Returns array with selected items
$request->except(['key1']); // Returns array with everything except key1.
```

You should always check the class for methods you can use. Just browse through the files and see what they have to offer. It's fun and gives you a better understanding of the api.

Laravel really shines with its extensive [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs), make sure you take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to array:
$request_arr  = (array) $_REQUEST;

Comment: sorry, but unfortunately, since the $_REQUEST (inside the larval method) gives an empty array, the output of (array) $_REQUEST is also an empty array.

Comment: Try this variant
$request_arr = (array) Illuminate\Http\Request;